# Does XEN PVH mode requires Intel VT-x or AMD-V HW virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

Hello Humble Stackoverflow users,

According to this [XEN article](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Understanding_the_Virtualization_Spectrum), PVH mode keeps all components paravirtualized except Pagetables - "but instead of requiring PV MMU (often called paravirtualized page tables), it uses the HVM hardware extensions to virtualize the pagetables".

Accoring to link i've provided above and wiki, you can learn that Pagetables are heavily connected with CPU workflow. However, following [article](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/655446-an-introduction-to-paravirtualization-and-xen) sais that HVM hardware Extensions are providing CPU virtualization - "Technically speaking, HVM refers to a set of extensions that make it much simpler to virtualize one component: the processor."

At the end all this left me in confused state.

Does XEN PVH mode requires Intel VT-x or AMD-V HW virtualization or not?

Regards,

Leshcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pvh only works with intel vt for now and there is no support for 32bit guests yet, as you can see in the readme

http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/unstable/misc/pvh-readme.txt
**Following remain to be done for PVH: AMD port.**

https://blog.xenproject.org/2015/01/15/less-is-more-in-the-new-xen-project-4-5-release/

**PVH initial domain support for Intel has been added and now supports running as dom0 and FreeBSD with Linux platforms**

Comment: i didnt see any note in readme that "Intel VT" is applicable for PVH only:
>At the moment HAP is required for PVH.

HAP is - Hardware Assisted Paging, a Xen abstract paging layer for Intel's Extended Page Table and AMD's Nested Page Tables.

However, you are right regarding x64 only guests:

>At present the only PVH guest is an x86 64bit PV linux.

Comment: sorry that part is in another document, but you can find "AMD port" in the todo list, I've added additional info